# SetState in an Axios call is not working in a react app

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am having the following code:

```
    interface IFishClass {
        title: string;
        description: string;
        date: string;
        id: string;
        lessons: string[];
    }

    const [FishClass, setFishClass] = useState<IFishClass>();


useEffect(() => {
  axios.get("/api/v1/class/" + params.id).then(
    (response) => {
      console.log("axios call: " + response.data);
      if (Array.isArray(response.data)) {
        setFishClass(response.data[0]);
      } else {
        setFishClass(response.data);
      }
    },
    (error) => {
      console.log(error);
    }
  );
}, []);
```

Two things are strange first setFishClass does not set the Object correctly. Second the Object sometimes seems to be an Array... What am i doing wrong and how can i solve this more elegant?

The Endpoint is a java spring endpoint and it returns a list of FishClasses:

```
public List<FishClass> getClasses() {
    return classRepository.findAll();
}

@Data
public class FishClass implements IClass {

    private String title;
    private String description;
    private String date;
    @Id
    private String id;

    private List<String> lessons = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

The console.log looks like this

response.data:

```
    {title: 'Yoga for beginnners 1', description: 'learn the basics of yoga', date: null, id: 'c90520c2-be25-4076-b23a-d28f15ac33ab', lessons: Array(44)}
    date
    : 
    null
    description
    : 
    "learn the basics of yoga"
    id
    : 
    "c90520c2-be25-4076-b23a-d28f15ac33ab"
    lessons
    : 
    (44) ['d524e740-9b40-4aa6-8af5-a64f18019ddb', 'c09e0b16-1d13-45e3-942e-4232233bb6ec', 'f8e17bd7-81a2-4a22-9567-38a1641db2ad', 'edac3714-f61a-49ee-ac96-03ca557f1132', 'cd62f6b8-bc6e-496c-ab73-6e5511392841', '49a3dbab-a0ef-4551-9795-29d4d13d1837', '86f12e74-ee09-41fc-a8ae-c89b580b5a07', '5d7a8a9d-eef1-4f7a-be62-62bae191ae04', 'af32d272-78c5-401a-888e-141ee2da57c8', '7e140ef8-0dcf-40fa-941c-dcfb870bbb5a', '7e97ca95-bfbc-4182-afc3-6ed0cd417226', '2716d715-8d39-4fb7-8b3f-a6e825d35afd', '7018efa3-7276-4453-a0ef-36fb412b531a', 'c0cb0e5a-d563-421a-b63d-44f7aa19e641', '2ae1c002-4ec1-43b4-b00b-b12a716d440c', 'fa9ecfd5-2c07-409f-a1c4-7b6a8204d70a', '60d90eee-7243-4f7e-accd-d36e8adc6269', '3a5f42c2-9109-4e57-8bc2-453428a34778', '0b7c1b24-685a-4e14-9989-010fc6fb21b6', '4c63232f-924a-4f6a-841c-48ec9fdad70f', 'bcd7d846-1659-4131-8143-a2a74a8ace9c', '6f20e99d-a94b-4d24-8592-2060bfe4a906', 'd9780514-e4e1-4889-92b2-202da2bf7417', 'd52ea15b-90ab-4764-9045-755692891510', '1c3e8144-b19c-4e4d-b2e1-b8d155e2507e', '8ec7b67d-e52d-4921-9f7c-25e88ae7a4f3', 'b5b3728a-f229-45da-8f4f-6f3426461169', 'fbd9b20c-878b-4cd4-b19f-e305bf023b53', 'f7723897-db2e-4ab9-9d96-e53a10e2b215', 'b116da97-8cfe-44e0-9c60-8909d066275a', '7ef1e3df-af9d-453f-a9d5-a3939b6955ff', '02276bff-60ee-445a-8f47-3bd1870b3927', '95a8d9ac-a1be-412a-a5b5-90a622d1f3a1', 'ee7fcb1d-2d5a-467e-bb49-c2a8845dd501', '330e08fc-7504-4c5c-802e-46c1618eb8dd', '5e01d51f-556a-4cf4-a5ec-6da517ac8df6', '0efc1504-0d7a-477d-8696-787c2b8326fb', '34be3a34-aabb-4d11-b540-4bec2bb825da', 'c235c06f-6373-4863-8e18-e8bc6962996c', 'b763a112-9c8c-409e-906d-341f47874b50', '56ab8d6b-1e19-4e1c-9256-23ab38f98827', 'a8c15756-450d-42d8-86e1-4481164f6995', '5c52bcf4-60e4-4018-914a-fbe68b2c5acd', 'e21acbb9-a65e-42a6-9458-2e60701fbb43']
    title
    : 
    "Yoga for beginnners 1"
    [[Prototype]]
    : 
    Object
```

but the console.log(FishClass) is undefined

MMh, even a simple

const [test, setTest] = useState("nobody is here");

setTest("Hello");
console.log(test);

does not work...

Comment: What is the expected type/value of response.data? What is being displayed in the console.log exactly?

Comment: I added some Information from the backend

Answer (score 2):

if you are not confirmed which data type the response data will be
you can simply modify your code. first set the data and then when you are using it for your specific use case then apply the conditions or destructure it.

```
  useEffect(() => {
  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get("/api/v1/class/" + params.id);
      setFishClass(response?.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  fetchData();
}, []);
```

Comment: the strange thing is, SetFishClass does not throw an exeption or something, it is just not working....

Answer (score -1):

You're using `.then()` instead of `async and await` you need to wait for data to store in state.